# Karate - GraphQL - How to verify schema and then response?

Tags: java, automated-tests, cucumber, graphql, karate

I have finally gotten Karate working with GraphQL and able to verify a simple 200 response though I am having trouble verifying the schema and then a response. I am super new so I apologize (not a programmer, just a tester).  I want to verify that the schema is correct and for example that the results simply return (providerID, firstName, lastName etc), not the data.  I then want to verify the data itself separately. The other thing I do not understand is how to pass in data, for example where I could change the Latitude, Longitude, MaxDistance etc and have it be a variable.  I see in the example how "name" as used as a variable yet these seem to be passed in differently so I'm unsure how to do it.  Sorry for not knowing so much, I appreciate the help.

```
Scenario: simple graphql request
    #Verify 200 response status returned    
    Given text query =
        """
     {
                    Results: getSearchResults(searchLatitude:"38.942833", 
    searchLongitude: "-119.984549", providerType: "Primary Care Physicians", 
    sortBy: "distance", maxDistance:"600",skip: 0, take: 10) {
                        providerID
                        firstName 
                        lastName
                        mI
                        title
                        name
                        nameLFMT
                        status
                        specialties
                        locations
                        institutions
                        acceptNewPatient
                        imageUri
                        distanceToNearest
                    }

    } 

        """
    And request { query: '#(query)' }
    When method post
    Then status 200

    # pretty print the response
    * print 'response:', response


    # the '..' wildcard is useful for traversing deeply nested parts of the 
    json
    * def results = get[0] response..Results
    * match results contains { ProviderId: 520, firstName: 'Richard', 
lastName: 'Botto' }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [`replace`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#replace) keyword.

Then try this:

```
Given text query =
    """
 {
                Results: getSearchResults(searchLatitude:"<searchLatitude>", 
searchLongitude: "<searchLongitude>", providerType: "Primary Care Physicians", 
sortBy: "distance", maxDistance:"600",skip: 0, take: 10) {
                    providerID
                    firstName 
                    lastName
                    mI
                    title
                    name
                    nameLFMT
                    status
                    specialties
                    locations
                    institutions
                    acceptNewPatient
                    imageUri
                    distanceToNearest
                }

} 

    """
* replace query.searchLatitude = '38.942833'
* replace query.searchLongitude = '-119.984549'
```

Once you get this working search the documentation for "graphql" for more ideas.

For matching schema it should be easy:

```
* match results contains { ProviderId: '#number', firstName: '#string', lastName: '#string' }
```

The doc has a whole section on [fuzzy matching](https://github.com/intuit/karate#fuzzy-matching).

Comment: @PeterSmith, the replace was great, thanks.  I have been fighting with the match results contains still.   I tried it with a simpler GraphQL query and response with no luck.  The simpler query returns a lengthy array/object that looks like the following (10 in the array) but I can't  figure out how to implement.     data: '#object',{
      getClaimHeadersList: '#array',[
        {
          claimNumber:'#string',
          claimStatus: '#string',
          totalPatientResponsibility:'#number',
          providerName: '#string',
          memberName: '#string'
        }
      ]
    }

Comment: @Jo-AnneB sounds like you just need to get used to nested JSON and arrays. I suggest you mark this answer as accepted and open a new question with a simple example of a response JSON you want to validate. you can also go through some of these examples: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-junit4/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/junit4/demos/schema-like.feature